# Blogger: How do I hide widgets in specific pages in mobile?

Tags: blogger

I want to hide widgets in pages like privacy policy and disclaimer. 
I tried   
But this hides it only in desktop view.
I want to hide it both in desktop and mobile.

Comment: Hi Siddharth, could you provide us with live link of your blog? We may be able to give you correct code that will hide mentioned widgets on both desktop and mobile view.

Answer (score 0):

Use display to none to hiding your specific element/widgets for all page or visibility to hidden for hiding only a text or whatever stuff indeed. Try put this:

```
display: none;
```

Or

```
visibility: hidden;
```

To your ID or class.
Hope this help.